# Avoiding underflow with equations of the form $\binom{n}{x} p^a (1-p)^b$

Tags: numerical-value

I have the need to evaluate equations of the form

$$\binom{n}{x} p^a (1-p)^b$$

where the values of $p$ are between 0 and 1 and $n$, $x$, $a$, and $b$ can be very large numbers.

I attempt to use

```
parms = {n -> 200, x -> 103, a -> 105, b -> 98}; 
e = Exp[LogGamma[n + 1] - LogGamma[x + 1] - LogGamma[n - x + 1] + a Log[p] + b Log[1 - p]] /. parms
```

but this gets converted back to

```
82791133891761429477050485625917802548514807100408460044000 (1 - p)^98 p^105
```

I was thinking that the interior of `Exp[...]` would get evaluated first but that doesn't happen. When I need to plug in certain values for $p$ I can get underflow errors.  For example,

```
e /. p -> 0.001
```

results in

[image: Underflow error]

How can I evaluate such constructions without getting underflow errors?

Comment: One way to ensure that `Exp` doesn't evaluate until you want it to is to use an `Inactive[Exp]` instead: 
`e = Inactive[Exp][LogGamma[n + 1] - LogGamma[x + 1] - LogGamma[n - x + 1] + a Log[p] + b Log[1 - p]] /. parms`. Then `Activate[e /. p -> 0.001]` seems to work!

Comment: Just set the precision of `p`, e.g., `e /. p -> 0.001\`10`

Comment: Or use exact numbers: `p->1/1000`.  Then you can apply `N`.

Comment: `e[n_, x_, a_, b_][p_] := Exp[LogGamma[n + 1] - LogGamma[x + 1] - LogGamma[n - x + 1] + a Log[p] + b Log[1 - p]]` and then `e[200, 103, 105, 98][0.001]` gives 7.50588e-257.